# How to enlarge memory limit for an existing pod

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

In openshift, how can I enlarge memory usage for an existing pod from 2GB to 16GB? As currently I always get run out of memory.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the OOM limitation as "1." process, and lower OOM priority through "2." process.

1. Check if "resources.limits.memory" of your pod is configured sufficient size or not.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: frontend
spec:
  containers:
  - name: db
    image: mysql
    resources:
      requests:
        memory: "2Gi"
      limits:
        memory: "16Gi"     <--- If this memory usage is reached by your application, triggered the Out of Memory event. 
:
```

2. Configure the same size with "resources.requests.memory" and "resources.limits.memory" for lowest priority of the OOM.
   Refer [Quality of The services](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/admin_guide/overcommit.html#qos-classes) for more details.

```
// If limits and optionally requests are set (not equal to 0) for all resources and they are equal, 
// then the container is classified as Guaranteed.

apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: frontend
spec:
  containers:
  - name: db
    image: mysql
    resources:
      requests:
        memory: "2Gi"  <--- set the same size for memory
      limits:
        memory: "2Gi"  <--- in requests and limits sections
:
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this section to your deploymentConfig file.

```
spec:
  containers:
  - name: nginx
    image: nginx
    imagePullPolicy: Never
    resources:
      limits:
        memory: "16Gi" 
      requests:
        memory: "2Gi"
```

and if the problem persists then, I would suggest look for HPA(Horizontal pod autoscaler) which will increase pods based on cpu and memory utilization so that your application pod will never get killed. Check out this link for more info

https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/dev_guide/pod_autoscaling.html

The most OOM Killed problem occurs for Java application so, setting env you can limit the application memory usage(which normally caused by heap memory usage) so you can limit those by just setting env veriable in your deploymentConfig under spec section.

```
spec:
  containers:
  - name: nginx
    image: nginx
    imagePullPolicy: Never
    resources:
      limits:
        memory: "16Gi" 
      requests:
        memory: "2Gi"
    env:
    - name: JVM_OPTS
      value: "-Xms2048M -Xmx4048M"
```

or you could use this

```
env:
- name: JVM_OPTS
  value: "-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseCGroupMemoryLimitForHeap -XX:MaxRAMFraction=1
```

By using any of these env variable your application will respect the memory limit set on pod level/container level(means it will not go beyond it's limit and will do garbage cleanup as soon as hitting memory limit)

I hope this will solve your problem.